Vue/Cordova/Android - WebView Memory Leak
I have a very simple Vue 2 application that looks through a list if URLs and Video.
The URLs are displayed in an iframe, and the videos are displayed in a video element.
The pages display for 15 seconds. The videos range from 6-25 seconds in length and are 4k videos.
This all works great in the Windows browser. No signs of issues.
I then add Cordova 12 and Android 11 as a platform.
I then created an APK, and sideload on custom Android device.
The app loads and runs for 5-10 minutes. Eventually the device runs out of memory, and I get a crash. The log says it was an error in the WebView, but I was watching the memory usage and I know the issue is it ran out of memory.
It appears the Webview (com.android.webview version 83) is not cleaning up the resources.
I have a CustomIframe.vue like so:



<script>
export default {
  props: {
    src: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    this.cleanupIframe();
  },
  methods: {
    cleanupIframe() {
      // Clear the src attribute to help free resources
      if (this.$refs.iframe) {
        this.$refs.iframe.src = 'about:blank';
        this.$refs.iframe.remove();
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
</style>

My main component that does the looping is called IframeSwitcher.vue:
<template>
  <div class="media-container">
    <div v-if="loading" class="loading-indicator">
      <p>Loading content, please wait...</p>
    </div>

    <CustomIframe v-if="!loading && isIframe" :src="currentUrl" />
    <video v-if="!loading && isVideo" ref="videoElement" autoplay muted playsinline controls>
      <p>Your browser does not support the video tag.</p>
    </video>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import CustomIframe from './CustomIframe.vue';
import { storeVideosInIndexedDB, getVideoUrlFromIndexedDB, clearIndexedDB } from '../indexeddb.js';

export default {
  components: {
    CustomIframe,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      loading: true,
      mediaItems: [
        { type: "iframe", url: "https://..." },
        { type: "video", name: "001.mp4" },
        { type: "iframe", url: "https://..." },
        { type: "video", name: "002.mp4" },
        { type: "iframe", url: "https://..." },
        { type: "video", name: "003.mp4" }
      ],
      videoFiles: ["001.mp4", "002.mp4", "003.mp4"],
      currentIndex: 0,
      intervalId: null,
      currentUrl: null,
      currentVideoUrl: null,
      isIframe: false,
      isVideo: false,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    clearIndexedDB()
      .then(() => storeVideosInIndexedDB(this.videoFiles))
      .then(() => {
        this.loading = false;
        this.startSwitching();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error during IndexedDB operations:', error);
        this.loading = false;
        this.startSwitching(); // Continue even if there are errors
      });
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalId);
    this.cleanupMedia();
  },
  methods: {
    startSwitching() {
      this.loadMedia();
    },
    loadMedia() {
      const currentItem = this.mediaItems[this.currentIndex];

      this.cleanupMedia(); // Clean up previous media

      if (currentItem.type === "iframe") {
        this.isIframe = true;
        this.isVideo = false;
        this.currentUrl = currentItem.url;

        // Display iframe for 15 seconds
        this.intervalId = setTimeout(() => {
          this.nextMedia();
        }, 15000);
      } else if (currentItem.type === "video") {
        this.isIframe = false;
        this.isVideo = true;

        getVideoUrlFromIndexedDB(currentItem.name)
          .then(blob => {
            if (blob instanceof Blob) {
              const reader = new FileReader();
              reader.onload = () => {
                this.currentVideoUrl = reader.result;
                this.$nextTick(this.forceVideoPlayback);
              };
              reader.onerror = (error) => {
                console.error("Error reading video blob:", error);
                this.nextMedia(); // Skip to the next media item if there's an error
              };
              reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
            } else {
              throw new Error("Retrieved data is not a valid video Blob.");
            }
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error("Error loading video from IndexedDB:", error);
            this.nextMedia(); // Skip to the next media item if there's an error
          });
      }
    },
    forceVideoPlayback() {
      const video = this.$refs.videoElement;
      if (video) {
        video.src = this.currentVideoUrl;
        video.load();

        video.onended = () => {
          this.nextMedia();
        };

        video.play().catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error trying to play the video:", error);
          this.nextMedia(); // Skip to the next media item if there's an error
        });
      } else {
        this.nextMedia(); // Skip to the next media item if there's no video element
      }
    },
    nextMedia() {
      clearTimeout(this.intervalId);
      this.currentIndex = (this.currentIndex + 1) % this.mediaItems.length;
      this.loadMedia();
    },
    cleanupMedia() {
      try {
        this.isIframe = false;
        this.isVideo = false;
        this.currentUrl = null;
        this.currentVideoUrl = null;

        const video = this.$refs.videoElement;
        if (video) {
          video.pause();
          video.src = '';
          video.load();
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error during media cleanup:", error);
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.media-container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.loading-indicator {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #333;
}
</style>

My real application is way more complex, and it suffers from the same issue.
I also tried using WebView version 114 but got the same behavior.
I also tried using a global iframe to avoid recreating a new one each time, but it just took longer to crash. It still crashed.
Any ideas?
